# Count Opps that do not contain X in any items

Tags: sql, netsuite

Would like to create formula(numeric)results field in saved search that counts Opps that don't have "x" in any of the items contained in Opp

I have tried INSTRA but do not know how to include ALL items in Opp. When I do use ISTRA it returns if X doesn't exist

```
ERROR: Field Not Found

INSTR{('SLII'},{custcol_ava_item})

returns if X doesn't exist 
ERROR: Field Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to group by Document Number for this to work.  Add a Formula(Numeric) column with this formula and Sum by this line.

```
case when INSTR({custcol_ava_item}, 'x') > 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

You don't need to keep this field, but it helps to understand what's happening in the next step.

---

On the Criteria -> Summary tab, set these values:

Summary Type: Sum

Field: Formula(Numeric)

Formula: `sum(case when INSTR({custcol_ava_item}, 'x') > 0 then 1 else 0 end)` Equal to: 0

Now when you run your search, it will only show you opportunities that have no line items with 'x' in the tax item name.

Comment: This is very helpful-- but I should revise my needs. I have a large amount of data and I actually need to COUNT the number of Opps where X does not appear in Program (which is an Item field- {item.custitem_program}).  I have several columns.. one is a Non-X program count and one is a count of programs that DO contain Y.. others still are columns that are counting Opps by stage.  Unfortunately, program is by line item and I just need to count the Opp once if ANY of the lines in the Opp do NOT contain a program of X and separately those that DO contain a program of Y

Comment: I used this formula sum(case when INSTR({custcol_ava_item}, 'x') > 0 then 1 else 0 end) Equal to: 0   and it returned an error message saying the formula contained an error... Any suggestions? @Mike Robbins

Comment: You're putting that formula in the Criteria tab, Summary sub-tab, correct?

Comment: yes-- but I'm attempting to count the number of opps, not filter to show only them.When i got around the error message, it only counted "1" for every single person represented, which is not correct.